# In Android Studio all emulators with API 33 show low xdpi and ydpi values of 72

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, dpi

I use the DisplayMetrics xdpi and ypdi values to scale graphics on my view for different devices. When I run my app on emulators with API 33 then the graphics are not scaled properly, they are way too small. I checked the values for xdpi and ydpi and they are at 72 which is very low. Usually they are something like 480.

Nexus 5 API 33
DisplayMetrics{density=3.0, width=1080, height=1848, scaledDensity=3.0, xdpi=72.0, ydpi=72.0}

Nexus 5 API 31
DisplayMetrics{density=3.0, width=1080, height=1776, scaledDensity=3.0, xdpi=480.0, ydpi=480.0}

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        Log.d("", "xdpi: "+metrics.xdpi+" ydpi: "+metrics.ydpi);
    }
```

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8815526, built on July 10, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

targetSdkVersion 32
```

It this a bug of the emulators? Can someone confirm this behaviour?

Comment: Have you reached to a conclusion on this one??

Comment: I have reported to google. Do not know if they fixed it already. From the list of emulators you can choose from there are some which do not show this behavior.